# Loop over subsets

Tags: r

I am very new to R ,
I have a DataFrame with :

```
df <- data.frame (id  = c("1", "1", "2" ,"2" , "3" , "3" ),
                  second_column = c("1.2", "1.5", "2.1" ,"2.2" , "3.3" , "3.4")
                  )
```

I would like to loop over the subsets of df

like this :

```
df_sub <- split(df, df$id)
```

How do I run one similar code to the lists that I find?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Take a look at `split()` in base R or combining `map()` and `filter()` from the tidyverse.

Comment: I tried df_sub <- split(df, df$id) , is there a way to run a similar code to the different subsets I have?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_split(id) %>% map(~.x %>% filter(second_column > 2))
```